# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable for calling function

Tags: python, function

I'm having the below code which is really simple, but I just can't figure out why I'm getting the above error. I can't seem to call the function defined above, as it is a boolean object??

```
def server(jobs):
    # master clock jumps to next job
    global master
    master = jobs[0][0]

jobs = [(1, 2.1),(2, 3.3),(3, 1.1),(5, 0.5),(15, 1.7)]

# master clock
master = 0
# server = true when busy, server = false when idle
server = False

next_arrival = jobs[0][0]
# assuming no future arrivals
next_departure = np.inf

job_list = []

print("master clock: " + str(master) + ", next arrival time: " + str(next_arrival) + ", next departure time: " + str(next_departure) + ", job list: " + str(job_list))
server(jobs)
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you overwrite your `server` function with `server = False` and then try to call that...

Comment: what is `server` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shadowed your function name with a bool variable when you wrote `server = false`. You can't have a function and a variable with the same name in the same scope.

Name that variable or the function something else, because `False()` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the name of the function. Change the function name from server to server_new and it will work.